# How to escape single curly braces angular 4 template

Tags: angular, angular-template

I have something like

```
<div ngNonBindable>
  yada yada.... { ... }  blah blah....
<div>
```

Even with 'ngNonBindable' directive I get error:

```
compiler.es5.js:1690 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Unexpected character "EOF" (Do you have an unescaped "{" in your template? Use "{{ '{' }}") to escape it.) ("
<div>
```

Two things:

1) Please point me in right direction.

2) Or, a workaround please.

Comment: The clue's in the error message: `{{ '}' }}`

Comment: I wanna keep the 'ngNonBindable' , cause I am gonna add other stuff which require it    ;-}

Comment: The suggested syntax after "use" in the error is absolute madness, and unreadable.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can bind the text to a string literal:

```
<div>
  {{"yada yada.... { ... }  blah blah...."}}
<div>
```

(if the text also has quote marks in it, you can escape them with `\`)

Edit: just saw your comment that you need to keep `ngNonBindable`.  It looks like there's an [open issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11859) for that, so until that's fixed you may need to see if you can restructure your markup to remove the escaped text from the `ngNonBindable` section.

Answer (score 30):

You can use Special Character for `{` -->   `&#123;`  and for `}` --> `&#125;`

```
<div>
  yada yada.... &#123; ... &#125;  blah blah....
<div>
```

Comment: yes but only one. If you add two, the angular compiler interprets it as `{{ }}` sadly

Answer (score 5):

```
<div>
  yada yada.... {{ '{' }} ... {{ '}' }}  blah blah....
<div>
```

there is a open [bug](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11859) for `ngNonBindable`