# Render jupyter notebook html file in Angular project

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, jupyter-notebook

I have created a new angular(angular 8) project. Also I have one jupyter notebook file(let's say python_practice.ipynb), I have downloaded python_practice.ipynb as html file so it is not python_practice.html
Inside the component.html I had pasted the content of python_practice.html to render the contents. But I am getting syntax errors in the browser console and content is not rendering.

````
Unexpected character "EOF" (Do you have an unescaped "{" in your template? Use "{{ '{' }}") to escape it.) ("


</html>
[ERROR ->]"): ng:///AppModule/ToolsComponent.html@18132:0
Invalid ICU message. Missing '}'. ("n class="o">=</span> <span class="p">[</span><span class="s1">&#39;col1&#39;</span><span class="p">,[ERROR ->]</span> <span class="s1">&#39;col2&#39;</span><span class="p">]</span>
<span class="n">data</span> <s"): ng:///AppModule/ToolsComponent.html@12695:132
Invalid ICU message. Missing '}'. ("39;Gender&#39;</span><span class="p">:</span><span class="s1">&#39;Male&#39;</span><span class="p">,[ERROR ->]</span><span class="s1">&#39;Address&#39;</span><span class="p">:</span><span class="s1">&#39;Hyderab"): ng:///AppModule/ToolsComponent.html@12788:378
Invalid ICU message. Missing '}'. ("39;Gender&#39;</span><span class="p">:</span><span class="s1">&#39;Male&#39;</span><span class="p">,[ERROR ->]</span><span class="s1">&#39;Address&#39;</span><span class="p">:</span><span class="s1">&#39;Hyderab"): ng:///AppModule/ToolsComponent.html@12854:378
Invalid ICU message. Missing '}'. ("39;Gender&#39;```

Moreover, inside my terminal I am getting errors like this :-
````

````
"Invalid ICU message. Missing '}'.",
"Unexpected closing tag \"h1\". It may happen when the tag has already been closed by another tag. For more info see https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#closing-elements-that-have-implied-end-tags",
```
````

But when I open python_practice.html file independently, it renders the page correctly. What am I missing?
Can't I use html+css+javascript syntax inside angular?
What are the possible solutions to deal with this?
Let me know if you need further information.
Thanks.

Edit :- python_practice.html file can be found here 
https://github.com/giteshjha/SharedFiles/blob/master/python_practice.html

Comment: `Can't I use html+css+javascript syntax inside angular?` By default, an Angular component is exactly this : one HTML + one CSS + one script file (usually Typescript). What does the HTML you're trying to paste in your Angular component look like? Can you paste the file (or at least the first few lines) in your question?

Comment: @JeremyThille Included the file. My concern is when it works fine while opening this html file independently but gives error otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Angular is expecting another curly brace at some lines in ur HTML, line 12789 has a single brace **{** , so u need to escape it to avoid this error,

try this answer :
 [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45619441/how-to-escape-single-curly-braces-angular-4-template)

Comment: I have gone through the provided link, it turns out that it's an open bug. None of the given solutions worked for the given file. Thanks for your response.